# Is there a way to we scrape Google Scholar based on key works using Python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, google-scholar

I am new to web scraping and was wondering if there was a way where the end result would be the title, abstract, year, publisher and authors of papers that came up when i try to scrape in google scholar for key words. I am not really sure where to go from here. I assume i need to keep a list of all the attributes i want but how do i search for them when web scraping?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, os, json
import pandas as pd


headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "Mental Health in Women",
  "hl": "en",
}

html = requests.get('https://scholar.google.com/scholar', headers=headers, params=params).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```